# Is constant_score faster in ElasticSearch queries if I don't care about scoring?

Tags: elasticsearch

I make several queries to ElasticSearch to retrieve documents by keywords (I match them by code or internal id's). I don't really care about scoring in those queries, just retrieving the documents.

Would wrapping the bool queries I use in a constant_score filter increase performance, or make sense whatsoever?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It make no sense. If you are using [bool](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html) query then you can apply filter to them.

```
GET /_search
{
  "query": { 
    "bool": { 
      "must": [
        { "match": { "title":   "Search"        }}, 
        { "match": { "content": "Elasticsearch" }}  
      ],
      "filter": [ 
        { "term":  { "status": "published" }}, 
        { "range": { "publish_date": { "gte": "2015-01-01" }}} 
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

**filter** - The clause (query) must appear in matching documents. However unlike must the score of the query will be ignored. Filter clauses are executed in filter context, meaning that scoring is ignored and clauses are considered for caching.

Even more `constant_score` should be used for scoring so if there is match apply "`boost`" value as a score.

To Sum Up: Use filter for filter and constant_score when you need score

Comment: If he doesn't care about scoring, then you can also move the `match` queries from the `must` part to the `filter` part, since `must` queries are scored.

Comment: @Val Here i just copied query from documentation to show how they can do it. And yes everything what doesn't require scoring goes to filter

Comment: @VolodymyrBilyachat From a performance point of view, is it better to put the matches inside the filter if I don't care about scoring?

Comment: @Mat-Tap i don't think you will notice difference but you should have a rule like if you need score put to queries if you need just to filter put to filter